# Dynamically fill html input

Tags: jquery

I have a link (a tag) that I want it to be dynamically be filled depending of what two other text inputs have as values, using jquery.

For example

```
Category: <input type="text" name="category"><br>
Sub-Category: <input type="text" name="subcat"><br>


<a href="http://domain.com/cat=$category/sub=$subcat">You will view $subcat under $category</a>
```

Any tip, guidance is appreciated.

Edit:
Filled with the input's value.

Comment: thank you for the welcoming downvotes. edit: thanks for the upvotes guys

Comment: You want them to be dynamically filled.... with/to what? The name of the inputs? The values of the inputs? Please edit your question and give more details of what you wish to achieve and please display what you have tried so far.

Comment: @NewToJS the values. Thank you for feedback will do immediately.

Comment: We also need another piece of information. When do you want the url to be updated? Live during typing? After pressing `enter` or `tab`?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/u4qzfzrf/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have added some class and id to textbox, a tag and on change event i set path,txt of a tag

```
Category: <input id="txtCategory" type="text" class='myEvent' name="category"><br>
Sub-Category: <input  id="txtSubCat" type="text" class='myEvent' name="subcat"><br>
    
    
<a id="myAnchor" href="http://example.com/cat=$category/sub=$subcat">You will view $subcat under $category</a>
```

---

```
$(".myEvent").on('input', function () {

    var category = $("#txtCategory").val();
    var subCategory = $("#txtSubCat").val();
    var set_hrefSrc = "http://example.com/cat=" + category + "/sub=" + subCategory;

    $("#myAnchor").html("you will view" + subCategory + " under " + category).attr("href", set_hrefSrc);

});
```

**[JsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ufpLoc76/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can change the text like :

```js
$("#subcat").on('change keyup paste', function() {
  $("#txtsub").text($(this).val());
  $("#nav").attr("href", "http://domain.com/cat=" + $("#category").val() + "/sub=" + $(this).val());
});
$("#category").on('change keyup paste', function() {
  $("#txtcat").text($(this).val());
  $("#nav").attr("href", "http://domain.com/cat=" + $(this).val() + "/sub=" + $("#txtsub").val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Category:
<input type="text" id="category">
<br>Sub-Category:
<input type="text" id="subcat">
<br>


<a id="nav" href="http://domain.com/cat=$category/sub=$subcat">You will view <span id="txtsub"></span> under <span id="txtcat"></span></a>
```

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

Basically the same as the accepted answer. Featuring basic validation in case a real validator would be overkill. Note that the title is misleading... it's not the input getting filled but rather the anchor tag.

```
<html>

<head>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="application/javascript">

    function your_update_function()
    {
        var category = $("#category").val().trim();
        var subcat = $("#subcat").val().trim();

        if(category && subcat)
        {
            var url = "http://domain.com/cat="+category+"/sub="+subcat;
            var htm = "You will view " + subcat + " under " + category;
            $("#fill_me").attr('href', url).html(htm);
        }
        else
        {
            $("#fill_me").attr('href','#').html('Please write something in both fields above');
        }
    }

    $(function(){

        $("#category, #subcat").on('input', your_update_function);
    });

    </script>

</head>

<body>

Category: <input type="text" name="category" id="category"><br>
Sub-Category: <input type="text" name="subcat" id="subcat"><br>

<a href="http://domain.com/cat=$category/sub=$subcat" id="fill_me"></a>

</body>
```

Should cover the topic (and does the trick).